# Loop through ConvertFrom-Csv returned object

Tags: powershell

I have below code which splits files based on certain column that we pass to it. I am facing issues while outputting results to csv file. As of now I am getting this output in csv

Company                     : ABC

Desc                        : DEF

Region                     : GHI

I need it in row column format

Company,Desc,Region

ABC,DEF,GHI

Code:-

```
function fBreakFiles() {
    param(
        [String]$pDirectory,
        [String]$pFileNameString,
        [String]$pDateColumnName,
        [String]$pNewFileString,
        [String]$pLogFile,
        [String]$pDateFormat
    )


    Get-ChildItem $pDirectory -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name -ilike "$pFileNameString" } | ForEach-Object {
        $FilePath = $_.FullName
        Write-Output "################ $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:fff') :: Starting to extract source file at location $FilePath  `r`n" | Out-File $pLogFile -Append

        # Open the CSV file for reading
        $streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($FilePath)

        # Get header line
        $header = $streamReader.ReadLine()

        # Set the buffer size based on your requirements
        $bufferSize = 2000
        $buffer = @()

        while ($streamReader.Peek() -ge 0) {
        # Read a block of lines into the buffer
        $buffer = 1..$bufferSize | ForEach-Object { $streamReader.ReadLine() }

        # Group the buffer data by required column
        $csvString = $buffer -join "`n"
        $csvObject = $csvString | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header ($header -split ',')
        $groupedData = $csvObject | Group-Object { $_.$pDateColumnName.Trim() }

        foreach ($group in $groupedData) {
            $DateString = ([datetime]::parseexact(($group.name), $pDateFormat, $null)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            $outputPath = Join-Path $pSourceDirectory "$pNewFileString$DateString.csv"
            if ($Date -ne $DateString)
            {
            $header | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputPath
            }
            $Date = $DateString
            $group.Group | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputPath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing obvious stands out. What have you done to diagnose the issue? Do you see the expected output contents in the console if you do ``Write-Host ($csvData-join"`n")`` right before piping to `Out-File` for example?

Comment: Have updated correct code which I am using

Comment: Only issue is I am getting data output in csv file in key value pair but I need it like normal csv data, rows and columns

Comment: Change `$group.Group | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputPath` to `$group.Group |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |Select-Object -Skip 1 |Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputPath` (just like in the code you initially posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mathias mentioned you need convert the objects back to CSV format before writing them to the file. `$group.Group | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputPath`

```
foreach ($group in $groupedData) {
    $DateString = ([datetime]::parseexact(($group.name), $pDateFormat, $null)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $outputPath = Join-Path $pSourceDirectory "$pNewFileString$DateString.csv"
    if ($Date -ne $DateString)
    {
        $header | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputPath
    }
    $Date = $DateString
    $group.Group | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputPath
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `$group.Group | Export-Csv -Append -Path $outputPath` instead.